# Can't run Intel Driver Update Utility on OS X

Tags: java, macos

I cannot run the Intel Driver Update Utility on OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.5). All Java options are enabled (have tested in Safari, Firefox and Chrome) and latest Java version installed. It keeps saying "Loading…" until a message pops up saying…

> The Intel Driver Update Utility failed. Possible web browser compatibility, firewall or installation issue detected. Select OK to troubleshoot the issue.

Any ideas?

<sup>PS: I don't use any other firewall software other than the OS included one.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the Intel Drivers Utility does not work with Mac OS.
It is only windows based application.

From http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/iduufaq:

> The Intel Driver Update Utility supports the following operating systems:
>
> ```
> Windows 8*
> Windows 7*
> Windows Vista*
> Windows XP*
> Windows Server 2008*
> Windows Server 2003*
> ```
>
> Operating systems **not supported**: Apple*, Linux*, and operating system emulators